# Highlight text in multiple EditText controls simultaneously

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, highlight

I've got the following problem: I'm trying to highlight text in multiple `EditText` controls simultaneously by calling `viewXYZ.setSelection(int, int)`, but the selection is only visible on the focused view.

Is there any way to bypass this, to highlight text in an unfocused `EditText`? Maybe by overloading the `onDraw()` methods?

Comment: `setSelection()` is not to "highlight text", but to set the selection for cut/copy/paste operations. Hence, it only makes sense on the `EditText` with the focus. What is your objective for highlighting text in multiple `EditText` widgets?

Comment: I know, but its (as far as I know?) the only way to mark text in an EditText control. I just want to convert certain input strings in realtime, and if you click on one section of the input string, I want to highlight the appropriate section of the output string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know, but its (as far as I know?) the only way to mark text in an EditText control.

EditText supports `Spannable` objects, so you can apply highlights to text (e.g., background colors) yourself.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/RichText/Search) demonstrates a search field that applies a background color to a larger piece of text based upon the search results. The key part is the `searchFor()` method:

```
  private void searchFor(String text) {
    TextView prose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prose);
    Spannable raw=new SpannableString(prose.getText());
    BackgroundColorSpan[] spans=raw.getSpans(0,
                                             raw.length(),
                                             BackgroundColorSpan.class);

    for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
      raw.removeSpan(span);
    }

    int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);

    while (index >= 0) {
      raw.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF8B008B), index, index
          + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
    }

    prose.setText(raw);
  }
```

Note, though, that your "output string" probably should be a `TextView`, not an `EditText`. `EditText` is for input, not output.